# Optimal assignment of +-1 values to vertices in a graph

Tags: graphs, optimization

Let $(V, E)$ be a simple connected undirected graph, $f: V \to \{-1, +1\}$, and $g: E \to \{-1, +1\}$. The function $g$ is completely defined by $f$, while $f$ is something we get to choose. The only thing we know about $g$ is that negating $f(v)$ causes $g(e)$ to negate whenever the edge $e$ is adjacent to vertex $v$, and that there are no other changes to $g$. The problem now is to choose $f$ to maximize $\sum_{e \in E} g(e)$. Is there are an efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

You may assume that the graph is of some specific form which includes trees as a proper subset. If the graph is a tree, then it is easy to come up with an efficient algorithm for this problem, starting from the root and moving towards leaves.

Comment: Your problem can be equivalently stated as:  Given a $n \times n$ matrix $H$ with all entries in $\{-1,0,+1\}$, the goal is to find a vector $v \in \{-1,+1\}^n$ that maximizes $v^\top H v$.  (Why?  It follows from your specification that $g(u,v) = f(u) f(v) H_{u,v}$.  Letting $n=|V|$ and representing $f:V \to \{-1,+1\}$ as a $n$-vector $x$ with all entries in $\{-1,+1\}$, and letting $H_{u,v}=0$ if $(u,v) \notin E$, we obtain the claimed equivalence.)

Comment: Good thinking. Here $H$ is symmetric, but not in general semi-definite.

Comment: Under some assumptions this problem could be solvable by quadratic programming allowing $f$ to have values in the interval $[-1, +1]$. I don't know what those assumptions would be though. The general problem has a kind of exponential feel to it.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions that quadratic programming is NP-hard for indefinite H. I'd be tempted to think the problem's integer quadratic program is also that for indefinite H.

Comment: According to https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~sdey30/QIP_NP.pdf, integer quadratic programming (IQP) is NP-hard, so it does not look good. The only wiggle room is that in contrast to IQP we do not allow $v_i = 0$ and that $H$ has values in $\{-1, 0, +1\}$, but not sure if that helps.

Comment: When the graph is assumed simple, the diagonal of $H$ consists of zeros. This means that the sum of eigenvalues of $H$ is zero. I wonder if this helps.

Comment: Take a look at this paper: http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~yury/papers/grothendieck-krivine.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [maximum cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut).

The function $g$ can be given explicitly as $g(\{u, v\}) = H_{\{u, v\}} f(u) f(v)$ for some $H \in \mathbb{R}^{E}$. Each choice of $f$ divides the vertices into two sets $V_+ = \{x \in V : f(x) = +1\}$ and $V_- = \{x \in V : f(x) = -1\}$. The  set of edges connecting $V_+$ and $V_-$ is the cut-set $C = \{\{v_+, v_-\} \in E: v_+ \in V_+ \text{ and } v_- \in V_-\}$. The term to maximize is

$\sum_{e \in E} g(e) = \sum_{e \in C} g(e) + \sum_{e \in E \setminus C} g(e) = \sum_{e \in E} H_e + 2 \sum_{e \in C} (-H_e)$

This is maximized by a maximum cut $C$ under edge-weight $-H_e$ for each edge $e$.

When there are both negative and positive weights, it is known that max-cut is NP-hard in general (min-cut is equivalent to max-cut with weights negated). In contrast, max-cut (min-cut) problem with non-positive (non-negative) weights has an efficient general algorithm.

Using knowledge of the structure of the graph may provide an efficient algorithm. It is easy to come up with an $O(n)$ algorithm when the graph is a tree, where $n$ is the number of vertices. For planar graphs, [there are algorithms](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10589-010-9335-5) which solve max-cut in $O(n^{3/2} \log(n))$ time.

Useful search terms include [submodular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function) and [Ising spin glass model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model).